# replacing old bits with new ones between two points

Tags: c, bit

I want to change the bits of `oldValue` between `hi` and `lo` to the bits of `newValue` also between `hi` and `lo` (leaving the other bits unchanged). What would a good starting point be?

Pseudo-code would be the most helpful!

```
int setField (int oldValue, int hi, int lo, int newValue) {     
    int x = 0;  
    if(lo > hi){
        int temp = lo;
        lo = hi;
        hi = temp;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you using the word "bits" as in (uh) *bits* -- ones and zeroes? If that is the case, are your `hi` and `lo` *bit positions* inside `oldValue`? (Note that your use of `newValue` strongly suggests you need a longer look in to whatever resource you are learning from.)

Comment: Ah: do you mean the bits between `hi` and `lo` in `oldValue` need to be replaced with those in the same position in `newValue`? (My comment above re: newValue was based on the thought this would *hold*, i.e., somehow `return`, the new value.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should return some result from this function or pass it by reference so any changes made can reflect outside of the function.

A good starting point could be to check out **[this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)** for bitwise operations, its well explained and it will provide more understanding for solving these types of problems.

Now back to our problem. First things first, lets clarify what the problem is by an example:

Inserting from bit `lo=2` to bit `hi=6`.
`oldValue = 1024` (showed in binary bellow)
`newValue = 127`  (showed in binary bellow)
`result = 1148`   (showed in binary bellow)

```
oldValue: 0000000000000000000001000[00000]00
                                    ^   ^
                                    hi  lo  

newValue: 0000000000000000000000000[11111]11 
                                    ^   ^
                                    hi  lo
```

Now we take all the bits from `lo` to `hi` of the `newValue` and insert them from `lo` to `hi` in the `oldValue`

```
result:   0000000000000000000001000[11111]00
                                    ^   ^
                                    hi  lo
```

Now, one way to achieve what you want:

Create a number of all 1's. Since it's an integer, it's size is 32 bits so there will be 32 1's:

```
int all_ones = ~0; /* 11111111111111111111111111111111 */
```

Now you create the left and right masks for the `lo` and `hi` bit portions. You need to understand **[bit-shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)** to understand the following explanation.

Perform a **logical right shift** (notice `unsigned`) to obtain the right mask:

```
int right_mask = ((unsigned int)all_ones >> (32 - hi - 1));
```

For `hi=6` We get all ones shifted to the right by 25 places:

```
right_mask = 00000000000000000000000001111111
                                      ^   
                                      hi
```

Perform a **logical left shift** to obtain the left mask:

```
int left_mask = (all_ones << lo);
```

For `lo=2` We get all ones shifted to the left by 2 places:

```
right_mask = 11111111111111111111111111111100
                                          ^   
                                          lo
```

And then use the left and right mask to obtain the masks for isolating the bits you need.

- For the `newValue`, we need to clear all bits **except** the bits from `lo` to `hi` because those will be inserted in the `oldValue`.
- For the `oldValue`, we need to clear the bits **between** `lo` to `hi` where the bits from `newValue` will be inserted.

Mask that will clear all but the `lo` to `hi` bits of the `newValue` (Only bits from `lo` to `hi` will stay what they were in the `newValue`, all others will be 0 (cleared)):

```
int clear_mask1 = left_mask & right_mask;
```

Using our example values for `lo=2` and `hi=6`:

```
clear_mask1 = 00000000000000000000000001111100
                                       ^   ^
                                       hi  lo
```

Mask that will clear the `lo` to `hi` bits of the `oldValue` (all bits between `lo` and `hi` become 0):

```
int clear_mask2 = ~(left_mask & right_mask);
```

Using our example values for `lo=2` and `hi=6`:

```
clear_mask2 = 11111111111111111111111110000011
                                       ^   ^
                                       hi  lo
```

Now you clear the bits left of `lo` and right of `hi` in the `newValue` by **bitwise and-ing** it with its mask:

```
newValue &= clear_mask1;
```

Using our example for `newValue=127`:

```
newValue = 00000000000000000000000001111100
                                    ^   ^
                                    hi  lo
```

And you clear the bits between `lo` and `hi` in the `oldValue` by **bitwise and-ing** it with its mask:

```
oldValue &= clear_mask2;
```

Using our example for `oldValue=1024`:

```
oldValue = 00000000000000000000010000000000
                                    ^   ^
                                    hi  lo
```

The final result will be the **bitwise or-ing** between `oldValue` and `newValue`.

```
00000000000000000000000001111100 bitwise-or with
00000000000000000000010000000000
--------------------------------
00000000000000000000010001111100
                         ^   ^
                         hi  lo
```

And we get to our value of `1148` :)

Solution Code:

```
int insertBits(int oldValue, int hi, int lo, int newValue) {
    int all_ones = ~0;
    int right_mask = ((unsigned int)all_ones >> (32 - hi - 1));
    int left_mask = (all_ones << lo);
    int clear_mask1 = left_mask & right_mask;
    int clear_mask2 = ~(left_mask & right_mask);
    newValue &= clear_mask1;
    oldValue &= clear_mask2;
    return (oldValue | newValue);
}
```

For the sample above, this code returns `1148`

Running code **[here](http://ideone.com/LVyf99)**

Comment: `Since it's an integer, it's size is 32 bits` That's not guaranteed, and it's an unnecessary assumption anyway. Maybe replace `int right_mask = ((unsigned int)all_ones >> (32 - hi - 1));` with `int right_mask = (1 << (hi + 1)) - 1;`.

Comment: @dxiv replacing `all_ones` with just `1` would lead to erroneous answers, as you would be only manipulating a single `1` bit instead of a number will all `1` bits, `all_ones`.  the only assumption here is that `all_ones` will be 32 bits long, which even if it was 16 bits due to differing OSs, then fixing that wouldn't be much of an issue.